# Serialize and Deserialize Property Based on DB Value

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xmlserializer

I have a simple class that has bool property.  The 'Get' logic for this property executes a stored procedure to return back a bit field from a database.

I then serialize this class and save it to an XML field in a database.  It saves the class and the bool property just fine, no problem.

The problem I seem to be having is when I deserialize this class.  The class deserilizes just fine, but when the data that drives the bool field has been updated, it seems that the class only recognizes what was serialized in XML, and it not looking back to the database to get the new bool value (does not execute my procedure to get the newly update bit field).

My solution has been to add the XmlIgnoreAttribute attribute to this field so it isn't serialized to begin with.  But I'm wondering if anyone noticed this and/or can help me understand the inner working of .NET XmlSerializer class.

Thanks!

```
[XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public bool IsUpdated
    {
        get
        {
            DataTable dtResults = mclsSQLServerTool.LoadDataTable("exec stp_RL_SEL_NameIsUpdated '" + mstrName + "'");
            bool blnIsUpdated = Convert.ToBoolean(dtResults.Rows[0]["RU_bitIsUpdated"]);

            return blnIsUpdated;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I thought (haven't checked) that XmlSerializer would ignore a get-only simple value (not a list). Is this your actual code? What did you *expect* to happen for a get-only?

Comment: I expected it to execute the proc and get the most recent value from the DB.  

And I believe you are right about the XmlSerializer and get-only values.  The code above is the most recent code where I have added the XmlIgnoreAttribute; I used to have a set block that was simply set{}

Comment: why would it do that? the deserializer isn't all that interested in getters (except for lists etc) - and even if it did run (it shouldn't) since it doesn't store anything anywhere... *how would you know?*

Comment: I don't think it was done intentionally, its just the way it was done.  It wasn't until we started to use this DLL and were noticing issues with this property, so we opened the code and noticed this and modified the code.  When we were debugging, the DB was always returning a result other than what the deserialized object was returning despite the SQL call.

So I'm just posting the question to try and figure out the inner workings of the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note here is that `[XmlIgnore]` is redundant; `XmlSerializer` is simply **not interested** in get-only properties (except for lists), because it knows it can't deserialize them. For example:

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get { Console.WriteLine("get_Bar"); return "abc"; } }

    static void Main()
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (SomeType));
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, new SomeType { Foo = "def" });
    }
}
```

outputs (minus the namespaces aliases etc):

```
<SomeType>
  <Foo>def</Foo>
</SomeType>
```

(note that `Bar` was not called)

For deserialization, the process (for simple values, not lists) is simple: as values are found in the the incoming xml stream, resolve them to members, and assign them - i.e. a xml-deserializer is basically a glorified switch statement based on incoming xml nodes.

It will *never* randomly call a "set" unless the data is in the incoming xml (and the property is read/write); and when it *does*, it *expects to assign a value*.

The interesting thing in your scenario is that your "get" doesn't assign the value anywhere - there is no cache. So actually, it doesn't *matter* that `XmlSerializer` doesn't touch it - every time you access `IsUpdated` it will do the query. Personally I suspect that is a mistake, and could lead to aggressive and unpredictable data querying.

Many serializers support the concept of serialization callbacks, which would allow you to perform some code at the end of serialization; however, `XmlSerializer` ***does not*** support this. So that isn't an option.

It isn't very clear what you want to achieve, but I'd just call a method at some point.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the replies.  What I'm after is a better understanding of how the serializer works under this scenario. I haven't used it much, and especially like this, so I was looking for any information to explain the results I was seeing (Google searches for this specific of a problem were thin :) )

I think the method-call may be a good change to this code.

Comment: @BrianG the *behaviour* is simple: it serializes anything public that it can both read and write; then it reverses that. It neither serializes nor deserializes your property, because it isn't read+write.

Comment: Ignoring that the blank set block (set{}) is poor coding and serializing this property is useless, is there a way you can think of that immediately accessing the IsUpdated property after deserializing the class would return to me the serialized value and NOT the result of the code in the get method (SQL proc result in my case)?  Because is the behavior I was seeing.

Thanks again!

Comment: @BrianG again, **what serialized value**? A get-only property **does not serialize** under `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: again, there used to be set method that was blank (set {}) so it was getting serialized.

Comment: @BrianG right; gotcha - that wasn't in the question ;p Without the set, it won't be used *at all* - but even with the set, nothing you are doing is useful here, because you **are never storing any value** - any time you call the property it invokes the database. Happy to advise here, but I need to be very clear what you are trying to achieve - and right now your sample code **has nothing to deserialize**. There is no field to populate.

Comment: I see.  All I'm trying to achieve is a curiosity issue now (I've already modified the code to a method instead of the property).  But what I don't understand is that even though 'false' was being serialized and saved, if I had code like this:
`
Class obj = (Class)serializer.Deserialize(SavedValueFromDB)
if(obj.IsUpdated)
  //DoSomething`
I was always getting the serialized value for IsUpdated and it **was not** executing the SQL to get the latest value.  Curiosity is killing the developer :)

Comment: @BrianG because **you aren't storing any value in a field**. Every time you call the `get`, it hits the database. There is no state in the class.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is a mis-use of properties.  Properties should have little or no code behind them.  If this code was ever used in a client-server application you could potentially be making database calls from the client.  I would recommend changing this to a method call.  If you want to serialize the results then store the results of the "Convert.ToBoolean" in a property.  Now it is a bit clearer as to what the property value is.

Something like this...

```
public bool IsUpdated { get; private set; }

public bool IsDataUpdated()
{ 
     DataTable dtResults = mclsSQLServerTool.LoadDataTable("exec stp_RL_SEL_NameIsUpdated '" + mstrName + "'"); 
     IsUpdated = Convert.ToBoolean(dtResults.Rows[0]["RU_bitIsUpdated"]); 

     return IsUpdated; 
}
```

Comment: Yep, I agree, the method call would be a better plan for this type of property (or lack there of)